# Can you suggest a canvas library capable of SIMPLE 3d

Tags: html, canvas, 3d, textures, texture-mapping

What I need to do is create a simple preview of a minecraft "dude" with the correct texture applied.

I'm not concerned with complex animations (yet) or detailed lighting (yet) but I'd like to make it using canvas and not *rely* on WebGL(not really that widely supported yet).

What technologies would you recommend for this set of limitations?

Ah, also, I don't need to edit or save the skin or whatever, just a simple display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[THREE.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/) is a popular javascript 3D library, it supports both canvas and WebGL